# Multiple users working on WordPress admin at the same time

Tags: staging

We are working in team. When we work on a new website, we would like be able to work on the site at the same time without missing database changes. Is it possible?

Comment: Without more information it is really difficult to help you. If the site is on the internet and you both access it, there shouldn't be a problem. If it is not, it means you have some kind of custom solution where you need a custom fix for.

Comment: We are working on the development of the website at the same time and we need a wordpress version control system. The github version is not fully compliant. There is always something wrong with the database. We need an interface where we can combine all the developments.